# How to create the numbers at the end of equation in python-sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, equation

With the following code ,we can create every equation containing number at the end.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    100 + x &= y            \\    
    \frac{y}{x} &\ge 1.3    \\
    (100+x)-(100+x)z &= y 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now to write them in python-sphinx.

```
.. math::

    \begin{align}
        100 + x &= y            \\    
        \frac{y}{x} &\ge 1.3    \\
        (100+x)-(100+x)z &= y 
    \end{align}
```

After compiling it with `make html`,we get the below image:
[image]

You can see there is no numbers at the end of each line.
How to create the same equation with numbers at the end of each line in python-sphinx?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14110790/407651

Comment: Try with the method, can't get desired appearance.

Comment: To visually have the same effect, you can add `\tag{1}` (..2,3) to the end of each line, before the eof. But you can't refer that in your text with `:ref:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @ilke444 commented, you can add `\tag{1}` to end of each line. And if you need refer to one specific line, you can add label in line.

```
 .. math::
   \begin{align}
        100 + x &= y    \label{a}   \tag{1}    \\    
        \frac{y}{x} &\ge 1.3 \label{b}  \tag{2}  \\
        (100+x)-(100+x)z &= y \label{c} \tag{3} 
   \end{align}
```

output:

[image]

So you can refer it like this:

```
refer it inline :math:`\ref{a}`

refer it for single line:

.. :math:: \ref{a}
```

Notice: label should be unique, otherwise output will not be rendered.

## update: upgrade mathjax in sphinx now support auto numbering line as latex.

open `index.html` in `_build` directory and change mathjax script

```
<script async="async" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

change it to:

```
<script>
    window.MathJax = {
        tex: {
            tags: "ams"
        }
    };
</script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    id="MathJax-script"
    async
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
></script>
```

Now all line in `align` block will auto numbering.

related doc: [Automatic Equation Numbering](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/eqnumbers.html)

### Why `python-sphinx` behavior like this?

[source code for numbering in sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/491048dfbfa8bace9fd8bb11949ec40fcffe6097/sphinx/directives/patches.py#L188)

`Python-Sphinx` handle every math block as whole and assign numbering for whole math block. When generating html, it will ignore numbering within math block, and leave it to math rendering library (default is `MathJax`).

So indeed, the problem is why Mathjax don't support auto numbering line in align block, so you can refer to this answer

[How to number and reference multiline equations?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13342/mathjax-how-to-number-and-reference-multiline-equations)

By now, the only way is add tag to each line :(, no automatic way.

---

### BTW

If you only want one label for whole math block

As far as I know, `python-sphinx` provides option for generate number for each math block (by using `:label:`

```
 .. math::
   \begin{align}
        100 + x &= y    \\    
        \frac{y}{x} &\ge 1.3  \\
        (100+x)-(100+x)z &= y 
   \end{align}
   :label: abc
```

output

[image]

Label `(2)` because sequence number is generated due to its position in whole document.

And you can refer to it by

```
refer to it by :eq:`abc`
```