# How to put equation numbers on the right on readthedocs?

Tags: read-the-docs

readthedocs puts equation numbers above equations like this
[image: actual]

I would rather have them on the right as the default sphinx theme (and everywhere else!) does, like this
[image: to the right]

Comment: This issue can be solved by the answer posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509369/13577592. However, if any readthedocs devs see this, I'd like to suggest that this should be the default behaviour. In my opinion the numbers to the right look much nicer, and it is the conventional format (I can look for references if anyone cares, but I think it's pretty universal).